# Is it ok to downvote questions asking about difference between two things?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

Is it ok down vote a questions asking about difference between two things?

Just like

1. What is the difference between Intent `ACTION_SEND` and Intent `ACTION_APPCOMPAT_SEND`? Which one is better than other? When to use one over other?
2. What is the difference between `Android` and `Java`? Why Google developed Android?How it's working?

I mean this all questions answer found by only one Google Search.

Comment: It's ok to downvote anything you see fit since they are your rep points. These example questions are certainly worthy of downvotes and are too broad. Comparative questions can be suitable if they show research effort and a minimal understanding. But they would need to be much more specific than these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's ok to downvote whatever you feel like, as long as you're not targeting anyone with serial votes.

I'd say your examples definitely fall under "does not show any research effort" from the tooltip.

Comment: Yes. You're right but when i downvoted this type of question then OP asked me about reason and i gave a reason then after suddenly some one down voted my questions randomly then i was asked to that OP for reason to serial downvoted my questions and he told me that you downvoted my question so that i downvoted your questions. so is it right way to downvote a question? or give a reason to down vote?

Comment: If someone is downvoting you in retaliation, I think you should flag their behavior for a mod to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

Just from the tone of the title, your first example sounds like it could be a valid question. I don't know what it means in detail, and your question here on meta is the only Google hit for `ACTION_APPCOMPAT_SEND`, so it looks like it's an artificial question title.

The second one deserves an immediate close vote. Multiple close reasons could apply: Too Broad, Primarily Opinion Based, Off Topic. And also based on false information, but that's not a close reason (Google didn't originally develop Android).

In any case, you're obviously free to downvote anything you think deserves a downvote. It's subjective to some degree, and there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: If the first example were *the question* then it would still be too broad and primarily opinon-based ("Which one is better than other?"). But it *could* be a decent question if the author linked to the docs and any other relevant resources and stated what they understood them to be used for but wanted more clarification, IMHO.

Comment: @codeMagic: I think it really depends. If there are clear technical criteria to decide when one or the other must be used, it would seem like a fine question to me. If it's just a matter of personal preference, or very fuzzy criteria, it could be an opinion based question.

Comment: Yes, but I still think that, in those types of questions, the author needs to show some effort by explaining what they believe them to mean and how they should be used before just saying, "Someone tell me when to do this". If they have no idea then that's fine as long as they explain how they've tried to understand.

Comment: @codeMagic Yes. You're right but when i downvoted this type of question then OP asked me about reason and i gave a reason then after suddenly some one down voted my questions randomly then i was asked to that OP for reason to serial downvoted my questions and he told me that you downvoted my question so that i downvoted your questions. so is it right way to downvote a question? or give a reason to down vote?

Comment: @MD  Yes, downvoting is appropriate in those situations. I almost always leave a comment explaining why unless I feel it should be obvious or someone has left a comment explaining the problem as I would have...then I upvote that comment. If you are being serial downvoted then the system usually takes care of it. If they explicitly said that's why they downvoted you then I would probably flag for mod attention and explain it. I've used a lot of downvotes and explained why and I haven't been serial downvoted. Don't sweat it.

Comment: @codeMagic Thank you very very much for your response...Now, i got it. what i have to do.... again thanks to you...